# webアプリケーション開発時のブラウザチェックについて

Tags: javascript, html, css

ブラウザのチェックの際、
ブラウザのバージョンが同じ場合、OSのバージョンの差は気にする必要はありますか？
またあるとすれば、どのようなチェックの際に必要でしょうか？

チェックの内容は下記になります。
・レイアウトの確認
・javascriptの動作確認

例：
chrome ver63 android 7.0
chrome ver63 android 8.0
はブラウザの仕様は同じなのでいづれかをチェックすれば問題ないとなりますか？

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザのチェックとは何を指しているのでしょうか？試験の内容によるかと思います。
また、Androidであれば`AndroidシステムのWebView`のバージョンも重要になるのでは？

また[OSによりhtml5が動作しないため](http://mobilehtml5.org/)、ページが正しく表示されなかったりする場合があるものと思われます。
ただ単に画面のレイアウトだけを確認したいのであればブラウザのバージョン統一のみでもいいかと思いますが、
スクリプトをガシガシ使っていたり、動作や挙動まで確認したいのであれば動作環境についても確認した方がいいと思います。

何れにせよ問題があった場合は調査時に問題を再現させなくてはいけないので
動作環境の差異で動作してしまい結局尋ねることとなるのであれば
二度手間を省いて動作環境も控えておいた方がいいかとは思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
チェックの内容は下記になります。
・レイアウトの確認
・javascriptの動作確認

Comment: レンダリング、javascriptのエンジンは、ブラウザのバージョンに紐付き、OS間で差異はないものだと思っていますが違うのでしょうか。

Comment: @prankmail 一部勘違いをしていたので修正しました。(Webkitではなく`AndroidシステムのWebView`)
また、`javascriptのエンジンは〜`について間違ってはおりませんが、javascriptのコード中で何を行なっているのか不明であり、
ブラウザによっては依存しているシステムも違うため、ハッキリ断言はできないかと思います。

Comment: @prankmail あと他で言えば実機の種類にも影響されます。
例えば、別々の透過背景色を持つ要素を内包しスクロールするテーブルを作成した場合、
要素数によってスクロールした際にリソースが足りなくなり落ちる端末が発生するかと思います。